# How to correctly use findViewById if a class A extends class B extends Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

In Android, I have a class A which extends class B which extends an ActionBarActivity. Class A sets the content view. For some reason, I'm unable to access the view elements from Class B. How can I access the view elements (ex: TextView)? When I attempt to use findViewById in class B, it is always null.

```
public class A extends B {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

public class B extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        // myTextView is null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're inheriting things backwards.  Class B doesn't ever setContentView.

I think this is what you want:

```
public class A extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // A called setContentView(), so now we can find views by id.
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        // myTextView now is not null.
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Plow. My goal is to have class A act as a MainActivity. class B will be a NavigationDrawer (allows a sliding panel to appear in front of class A). I'd like to be able to have several classes extend from the NavigationDrawer, and allow the NavigationDrawer to access certain UI elements within that class. Is this possible

Comment: I don't know.  All the navigation drawers I've ever used were fragments.